# Background process which has no IO can be affected by keybord input?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, linux-kernel

when I type this command in shell

ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"&

I click “Enter” on keyboard continuely，and this process will be stopped like this：

[4]+  Stopped                 ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"

if I do not click the "enter" it will be done

why?

Comment: This is unclear. Please specify your keystrokes *exactly* and what you see interleaved with them. On my machine I get the "Stopped" message immediately after executing the command, without any further input.

Comment: doing `strace sleep 10` shows close(1);close(2); at the end .. looks like that is causing this behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

See the man page:

```
 -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.  A common trick is
         to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine.  For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and
         the X11 connection will be automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put in the background.  (This does not
         work if ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system, even without the keyboard input, it stops:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10" &
[1] 14986
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"
```

However, the following continues to run:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10" </dev/null &
[1] 15580
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10" < /dev/null &
```

Apparently `ssh` is looking for input and, as background process, can't get it.  Redirecting stdin from /dev/null tells it not to bother, and it continues running even in background.

**Update:**  This above matches what @BraveNewCurrency found in the documentation: to make `ssh` run in the background, input must be redirected from `/dev/null`, and `ssh` provides an option `-n` that, effectively, does just that.

Comment: but sometimes the process can be done,so I think if it is looking for input, it can nerver be done

Comment: [2]-  Done                    ssh 127.0.0.1 "sleep 10"